# Laravel Undefined Variable in View from database

Tags: php, laravel, web

i tried to show some data from database to my view. But i get undefined variable error.

```
Route::get('pages/tab-content-games', 'Admin\TournamentCrudController@get_data');
```

and this is my function

```
public function get_data(){
    $data['data'] = \DB::table('tournament')->get();
    return view('pages.tab-content-games', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

in tab-content-games.blade.php
i just print the variable

```
{{ print_r($data) }}
```

can someone helped me, what part i'm doing wrong. thankyou

Comment: please share exact error given by laravel ? or screenshots ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this `return view('pages.tab-content-games', compact('data'));`

Comment: `compact('var1', 'var2') is the same as saying array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2) as long as $var1 and $var2 are set.`, [Check here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php#118723)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
i think you have to use rural name as your database name `tournaments` instead of `tournament`. also you can use compact.

```
public function get_data(){
    $data = \DB::table('tournaments')->get();
    return view('pages.tab-content-games', compact('data');
}
```

PS: consider using model in your controller instead of using `DB` for simple functions.

```
use App\Tournament;

public function get_data(){
    $data = Tournament::all();
    return view('pages.tab-content-games', compact('data')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return view('pages.tab-content-games')->with('data', $data);
```

Comment: Please explain why `Try this` ?

Comment: you mean why I used capital `t` ?

Comment: No why should OP use `return view('pages.tab-content-games')->with('data', $data);`